# how to curve a part of a backgroud image using css3 or svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, curve

When you see the image, you see the curve with a background. I used `svg` to create the curve, but it's a solid color. Can someone explain me how I use a image as background instead of a color like the picture show it?

What I am trying to achieve

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

What I got

[image]

My code

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #333;
  bottom: 0;
}

#svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  bottom: -78px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg">
        <path d="M0 0 C50 20 50 80 100 82 C150 80 150 20 200 0" stroke="none" fill="#333"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="container" style="background: grey; margin-top: -20px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the image in the SVG (as an `<image>`) and use the path to make a `<clipPath>` or `<mask>` for that.

Alternatively you can do it by making the image into a `<pattern>` and using that for the path fill.

There are many examples of how to implement all of these solutions on this site and on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but I'm going to assume you're trying to turn an image into a circle. For this, put the image into a `class` then use the `border-radius` tag. 50% is a circle, 25% is an oval, etc.